# which way to set config for nesjt is better, ConfigModule or normal config model

Tags: angular, config, nestjs

There is an advice way to set config for `nestjs` in the website (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration).
It uses nestjs module, and has to be imported every module you use it. like

```
@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    ...
})
```

But I prefer to set config use normal node model as below:
        - config
        |- config/index.ts
        |- config/config.base.ts
        |- config/config.dev.ts
        |- config/config.prod.ts
I think the second way is more simple and more intuitive.Which one do you think is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches can be used at the same time. Basically, `ConfigModule` is nothing more than just a simple abstraction over your environment variables. You can still follow "normal node mode" but encapsulate these env-specific values inside your module. Generally, it simplifies testing because you don't have `process.env` hardcoded everywhere, instead, you use an exposed service which gives you strong typing benefits as well as capability to effortlessly mock your class' methods.

Reassuming, there is nothing wrong with the following structure:

```
|- config/index.ts
|- config/config.base.ts
|- config/config.dev.ts
|- config/config.prod.ts
```

It all boils down to how you want to access these values.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using environment variables (which is powered with `dotenv` package, described in docs) - it plays best when app is deployed as a Docker container.

Any configuration including credentials should not be published in your GIT repository (especially prod credentials).